# How can tampermonkey access chrome-extension:// to be able to interact scripts with extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

How can tampermonkey access chrome-extension:// to be able to interact scripts with extensions?
Now it writes that it doesn't have access to this page if you open the extension page.  I want to interact with a certain extension
I tried disabling security and adding // @include *chrome-extension://* , but it didn't help.

Comment: Extensions are not allowed access `chrome-extension://` so, you can't do it with a userscript

Comment: and there's a way around it at your own risk?

Comment: No, because googlE think its users are all morons, they can't think for themselves.

Comment: You can write your own extension that uses `chrome.debugger` API to send a CDP command like [Runtime.evaluate](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-evaluate) to the tab of that extension. There may be such extensions around, try looking. To hide the chrome.debugger warning you can add `--silent-debugger-extension-api` to your chrome shortcut.

Comment: Great idea, thanks